# Web frameworks with scaffolding and/or web based DB administration tools?

Tags: language-agnostic, database, web-frameworks, scaffolding, database-administration

I'm looking for web app frameworks and/or database administration tools, either popular and unpopular, written in any language, for any relational database.

In short, I'm looking for **web accessible CRUD front-ends with minimal programming effort**.

For example:

- [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) ([MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) administration tool)
- [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) (web app framework with scaffolding)

Answer (score 1):

It should be a community wiki, I think.

Seam has its (similar) scaffolding, with [seam-gen](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR1/reference/en-US/html/gettingstarted.html)

Answer (score 1):

Django is pretty hot and you can have it build models based on existing databases. And it's based on Python which is pretty easy to pick up.